# 4D and higher geometry

Tags: geometry

I can easily figure out 2D geometric properties and 3D geometric properties like for example the pythagorean theorem.

2D pythagorean theorem: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

3D pythagorean theorem: $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$

However in my Math World series there is a solar system with geometries from 2D to 10D.

How would I be able to figure out 4D geometric properties? I mean 4D geometry is much more complicated than 3D geometry because of 3D sides and 4 axes.

Comment: Try starting with geometric axioms and consider what happens when a point is uniquely represented by a 4-tuple.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just start with the 3D properties and expand them to higher dimensions?